# Manipular um arquivo txt com javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Bom, queria atraves de um arquivo txt, tranformar as linhas em arrays(se for melhor)
para procurar dentro dele uma sequencia com 9 numeros, para depois vincular à uma imagem.
obs:dentro dos txt's que serão lidos haverão mais de uma sequencia com 9 numeros.
da pra fazer isso com node ou outra tecnologia

```
const readline = require('readline')
const fs = require('fs')
const readable = fs.createReadStream('Marcas2507.txt')
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input : readable,
    output: process.stdout

})
rl.on('line',function(line){
   console.log(line) // Não sei como transformar o txt em um array para identificar uma sequencia de 9 numeros nele
})
```

Comment: Podes dar exemplos do que contem o `.txt`?

Comment: 916427416 

Publicação de pedido de registro para oposição (exame formal concluído) 
Titular: restrito
Data de depósito: 13/12/2018 
Apresentação: restrito
Natureza: restrito
Elemento nominativo: restrito
CFE: 27.5.1 
NCL(11): 41 
Especificação: restrito; 
Procurador: restrito

Comment: após a sequencia de 9 numeros(numero do processo) há uma quebra de linha

Comment: E o que queres fazer é extrair esses 9 digitos cada vez que aparecem? A estrutura é sempre igual? (ou seja: numeros > quebra de linha > texto | e o mesmo repetido N vezes)

Comment: Eu quero vincular esses 9 numeros a uma imagem(como se fosse uma nomeação de imagem atraves do numero do processo(os 9 numeros no caso). E sim sempre há uma quebra de linha toda vez que aparece esses 9 dígitos

Comment: Podias ler o ficheiro todo de uma vez e fazer algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/btLpn6x1/ é isso que procuras?

Comment: sergio, como eu identificaria essa sequencia de 9 numero desse JSON para vicular a uma imagem ou colocar dentro de um array? somente os numeros

Comment: Eu ainda não percebi completamente o que queres fazer... viste o meu jsFiddle? lá é criada uma array como procuras. Não era assim que pensavas?

Comment: Desculpa se não deixei claro, é o seguinte. eu quero desenvolver um software que leia um arquivo txt completo e extraia dele apenas os processos(sequencia de 9 numeros) e armazene esses dados de alguma forma, para que então eu vincule cada processo com uma imagem específica. no seu exemplo você armazenou todas as informações dentro do array. eu so quero armazenar o numero do processo.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/btLpn6x1/4/ ?

Comment: perfeito, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se pretendes extrair os numeros podes fazer assim, partindo do principio que a formatação do ficheiro é consistente:

```js
const txt = `
916427416 
Publicação de pedido de registro para oposição (exame formal concluído) Titular: restrito Data de depósito: 13/12/2018 Apresentação: restrito Natureza: restrito Elemento nominativo: restrito CFE: 27.5.1 NCL(11): 41 Especificação: restrito; Procurador: restrito

846483729 
Publicação de pedido de registro para oposição (exame formal concluído) Titular: restrito Data de depósito: 13/12/2018 Apresentação: restrito Natureza: restrito Elemento nominativo: restrito CFE: 27.5.1 NCL(11): 41 Especificação: restrito; Procurador: restrito
`;

const data = txt
  .split(/\n/g)
  .map(str => str.trim())
  .filter(str => {
    if (!Boolean(str)) return false;
    const match = str.match(/^\d{9}$/);
    return match && match[0];
  });
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
```

Na prática separas o ficheiro linha a linha e depois extrais só as linhas que começam e acabam com números, exatamente 9.